# What resources should I be learning to calculate my kernel size?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to build a Softmax classifier using Convolutional Neural Networks but I keep getting the following error from keras:

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 4 from 1 for 'max_pooling1d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,64].

I am using a reshaped dataset of the following sizes:

train_x(624,3,9)
train_y(624,2) after one hot encoding
test_x(150,3,9)
test_y(150,2) after one hot encoding

the 3D numpy array was reshaped from (624,27) matrix into (624,3,9) and so on.

I honestly think the problem comes from calculating the sizes of kernels and pool_size.

What resources should I be reading to get my input in a format that y network will admit?

Many thanks!

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from numpy import dstack
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=open('data/data_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[1:625]
train_x=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    train_x[i,:]=values

f=open('data/labels_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[1:625]
train_y=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    train_y[i,:]=values


f=open('data/data_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[626:776]
test_x=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    test_x[i,:]=values


f=open('data/labels_shuffled.csv')
data=f.read()
f.close()
lines=data.split('\n')
header=lines[0].split(',')
lines=lines[626:776]
test_y=np.zeros(((len(lines)),len(header)))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[0:]]
    test_y[i,:]=values

#reshaping data to have samples.
train_x=train_x.reshape(624,3,9)
test_x=test_x.reshape(150,3,9)


#one hot encoding
train_y=to_categorical(train_y)
test_y=to_categorical(test_y)



verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10000, 32
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
history=model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Just need to get a model prediction, either 1 or 0.

Pls help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your input size is only (3,9), and after two Conv1D filter, the size for each filter would be (1,1), just like what the error states, so a MaxPooling1D of size 2 will not work here.

One solution is probably to remove `pool_size=2` from the max pooling since your feature size is already a single value (i.e., you can consider it as the result from a max pooling and move forward).

Comment: Yes, it does work better after the tunning. Many thanks!